# Reference a file location / name from a cell within excel to open a folder or file

Tags: excel, vba

I work in a school environment where each school has its own filepath directory and location.

I have an Excel workbook with macros which open up other spreadsheets / files or folders.
I wish to share this with other people but they are using different servers, what's the best VBA coding to use to access a file location (Filepath \ Name saved within the MACRO spreadsheet in a tab sheet e.g. sheet name [References], Filepath\name stored in a cell for example cell B6.

I used a direct link within VBA which used the filepath / file name within the coding text.

Other users will require a different filepath source on their own system so I need to be able to reference the file path / name within the spreadsheet which each user can amend to their directory.

Comment: you already answered your own question use a cell value to reference to a folder path or a sheet name

Comment: I understand that that's what I need, but I am asking how the VBA code is written so that it does this and the best way for this to be written  e.g. should the action such as Explore.exe be in 1 cell  say B6 then the filepath in C6 and if required the file name in d6 and use VBA to concatenate the action/filepath/filename together or do this in the excel spreadsheet and get VBA to reference the 4rth (Concatenated) cell or does anyone have any better way of doing it - I am ok with using developer and making a macro  but not that confidant at actually writing a VBA Macro from scratch

Comment: braX, - Can you please advise the best way for doing the above query, I can set up a spreadsheet so that the filepath, file name, even a cell containing the version number in case the file  is updated  but not sure if I need the file type or any other data so that I can concatenate all relevant info in to 1 cell which I can then retrieve using VBA also what's the best way to run the concatenated filepath etc. - for example Explore.ex or what (Not up to spead with VBA)

Answer (score 0):

to get you started

example:

A1 is `C:\Users\JL\Documents\data`

A2 is `myworkbook.xlsx`

```
Sub OpenAndWriteToFile()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    'get the file path and name from cells A1 and A2
    filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    
    'open the workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "\" & fileName)
    
    'write "Hello" in cell A1 of Sheet3 of the opened workbook
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
    
    'save and close the workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```